# Can't view the image (hyperlink) in Published as Web Spreadsheet via Mobile

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this Apps Script wherein it publishes into web every single spreadsheet inside the google drive folder and sends the pubHTML link via email. This spreadsheet contains 24 images that were inserted using =IMAGE() formula in google sheet.

Issue: Employees were able to see the actual published to web spreadsheet via web, but when they tried to look at in via mobile, images aren't loading.

Here's a sample image link of the badge/icon -> https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9e_X60g3XTV_pPclJKIrMyR5biYPIRm4aXqnBFW2RwSvBHQbNULjm18Sqf1Sky0KIp1wgInYseX6uIkLYO1b1EuwKRiOZK9QWrmgJYkrHAxtx4MEZ9fSBQuOo7OHXfZFD51qqJDbYeU

and here's the actual view of the published to web spreadsheet

[image]

but in mobile, all of the 24 icons/badges aren't showing/loading.

Would you know what's causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 modes of inserting an [image](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en) on a spreadsheet:

=IMAGE(url,mode,height, width):

- **url** - The URL of the image, including protocol (e.g. http://)
- **mode** - [ OPTIONAL - 1 by default ] - The sizing mode for the image

  - 1 Resizes the image to fit inside the cell, maintaining aspect
    ratio.
  - 2 Stretches or compresses the image to fit inside the cell, ignoring
    aspect ratio.
  - 3 Leaves the image at original size, which may cause cropping.
  - 4 Allows the specification of a custom size.
- **height** - [ OPTIONAL ] - The height of the image in pixels. mode must be set to 4 in order to set a custom height.
- **width** - [ OPTIONAL ] - The width of the image in pixels. mode must be set to 4 in order to set a custom width.

How are you inserting it? 
Which mode are you using? Please, copy the code so we can reproduce it.

I can see properly your image from the web version on my phone using:

```
=IMAGE("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9e_X60g3XTV_pPclJKIrMyR5biYPIRm4aXqnBFW2RwSvBHQbNULjm18Sqf1Sky0KIp1wgInYseX6uIkLYO1b1EuwKRiOZK9QWrmgJYkrHAxtx4MEZ9fSBQuOo7OHXfZFD51qqJDbYeU")
```

Comment: Hi yuri. Sorry. Just to clarify. All the images in the spreadsheet are inserted manually with a mix of mode 1 and mode 1-4 because some of the images don't fit on the cell itself. What my apps script does is just replicating this spreadsheet, and dump it into google drive folder. 

I tried it at home and i can view in my mobile. but when here at the office, it's not working.

Comment: I would try to use the same format size for all and the same mode of insert for all. This would simplify the problem and help you to address it.

Comment: Thanks Yuri for your suggestion but I can't do it because some of the images has no fixed size. :( I'm still thinking why I can access it at home via mobile when I tried to set i up in my machine.

Comment: Check in another browser, it may be something related to it.